# Translate ActiveSync Mailbox id to EWS folder id

Tags: exchangewebservices, activesync

Do you know if it is possible to translate ActiveSync (calendar) Mailbox id to EWS folder id.
My main sync task uses Activesync protocol but for certain tasks I need to use EWS protocol. For now I used GUID of meeting to find out EWS instance of same meeting but since EWS does not support "deep" searching, firstly i need to find folder where this meeting is.
All i have is Active Sync mailbox id, it's parent mailbox id and display name which is not unique.

Does ActiveSync support some translate feature where I can reciveve EWS folder id and change key?

I need server respond in form like that:

```
FolderId Id="AAMkADc2NTc1MDc2LWU1YXXXXXXXXXXXXWRiMjlmNDgwNjkxZAAuAAAAAADwSBYV6TcMQa7GjEF/TzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXICzAAA=" ChangeKey="AgXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXACw=="/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only solution which I can think of is

1. Send SyncFolderHierarchy request using EWS, this will return list of folders in EWS.
2. Construct tree hierarchy using folder display name like Inbox/Folder1/Folder2 from both ActiveSync folders and EWS folders.
3. Create a mapping locally in client from ActiveSync folder ID to EWS folder id using above mapping.